# Trouble using ng-functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have 3 html pages (with 3 different angular controllers), every page displays a table with rows, and on every page the rows should either be displayed red or green (according to the errorstate):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="case in entries | filter:searchCase | orderBy:'-id' track by case.id" ng-class='setRowColor(case.errorstate_id)'>
    <td>{{case.name}}</td>
    ........
</tr>
<tr ng-if="case.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="3">{{case.errormessage}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now it wouldn't make sense to have 3 `setRowColor` methods (one in every controller), but I also can't create a factory service, since I wouldn't be able to call it inside `ng-class`.

So my idea was to make a normal JS function, and just use `class` instead of `ng-class`, but this doesn't seem to work along with `ng-repeat`.

here's the method:

```
function setRowColor(col) {
    return {passed: col == '0', failed: col != '0'};
};
```

whereas I have a `.passed` and `.failed` class in my stylesheet.

Is there a way of getting `class` to work? Or is there any better approach to solve my problem?

Comment: do you have the ng-repeat-end ?

Comment: what does setRowColor return?

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu I added the function to my answer, the method itself did actually work anyway when I had it in every controller

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu yes I have the ng-repeat-end

Comment: Is the function defined on $scope? $scope.setRowColor = setRowColor?

Comment: It works when defining it in the controllers $scope, but I'd have to define the exact same function in every controller then, which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

The function `setRowColor` should be defined in your controller's `$scope`.

```
$scope.setRowColor = function() {
    ...
};
```

To keep only one definition of this function you should create an `AppController` which would be set on the `body` tag:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    ...
```

Define the above function inside `AppController` and your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a ternary in the ng-class instead?

```
<tr ng-class="case.errorStateId===0 ? 'passed' : 'failed'"
  ng-repeat-start="case in entries | filter:searchCase | orderBy:'-id' track by case.id">
    <td>{{case.name}}</td>
    ........
</tr>
```